# R: row names of every list in a list of list

Tags: r, list

I have a list with 10+ lists. The list inside the list contained multiple rows.

I would like to get every rownames of every list inside the list without using a for loop.

I was expecting something like this: `rownames(a[1:16])`, but it didnt work.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

`names_list <- lapply(lists, rownames)`